# Fabric JS 2.4.1 Problem using Copy/Paste Example, Object(s) gets stuck in clipboard

Tags: fabricjs

Link to Example copy/paste code: http://fabricjs.com/copypaste

I am having a problem when I copy a textbox to the clipboard and paste a clone on the canvas, then try to replace the text of either the original or the copied textbox with text copied to the clipboard from notepad it pastes another textbox instead of the text from notepad.

I think I need the fabric js equivalent to:

```
if(typeof(window.clipboardData)=="text") {
  alert("this is text")
}
else {
  alert("this is an object")
}
```

I tryied Edge, Chrome, Firefox and Opera and got the same results.

Here is a link to a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Larry_Robertson/qzkpon02/)

Steps to recreate the problem:

1. Copy the textbox.
2. Run Notepad and type in some text "replacement text", then copy the text to the windows clipboard.
3. Select either the original textbox or the copy it doesn't matter which and paste in the text copied from notepad

The result is that it pastes a new textbox instead of the selected text in the textbox

If you re-run this example and just use the existing textbox it will successfully paste the text from notepad.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  selection: true,
});

textBox = new fabric.Textbox("copy me", {
  fontSize: 24,
  fontFamily: 'Verdana',
  fill: '#000000',
  textAlign: 'left',
  width: 200, // for 20 characters
  top: 0,
  left: 0
});
textBox.setControlsVisibility({
  mt: false, // middle top disable
  mb: false, // midle bottom
  ml: true, // middle left
  mr: true, // middle right
  tl: false, // top left
  tr: false, // top right
  bl: false, // bottom left
  br: false // bottom right
});
canvas.add(textBox);
canvas.renderAll();
var _clipboard = null;

function Copy() {
  // clone what are you copying since you
  // may want copy and paste on different moment.
  // and you do not want the changes happened
  // later to reflect on the copy.
  if (canvas.getActiveObject()) {
    canvas.getActiveObject().clone(function(cloned) {
      _clipboard = cloned;
    });
  }
}

function Paste() {
  // clone again, so you can do multiple copies.
  if (_clipboard == null) {
    return false;
  }
  _clipboard.clone(function(clonedObj) {
    clonedObj.set({
      left: clonedObj.left + 20,
      top: clonedObj.top + 20,
      evented: true,
    });
    if (clonedObj.type === 'activeSelection') {
      // active selection needs a reference to the canvas.
      clonedObj.canvas = canvas;
      clonedObj.forEachObject(function(obj) {
        canvas.add(obj);
      });
      // this should solve the unselectability
      clonedObj.setCoords();
    } else {
      canvas.add(clonedObj);
    }
    _clipboard.top += 20;
    _clipboard.left += 20;
    canvas.setActiveObject(clonedObj);
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  });
}

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  console.log(e.which);
  if (e.which === 89 && e.ctrlKey) {
    // control + y
    //replay(redo, undo, '#undo', this);
  } else if (e.which === 90 && e.ctrlKey) {
    // control + z
    //replay(undo, redo, '#redo', this);
  } else if (e.which === 67 && e.ctrlKey) {
    // control + c
    Copy();
  } else if (e.which === 86 && e.ctrlKey) {
    // control + v
    Paste();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" class="context-menu-one" width="864" height="450" style="border:2px solid black"></canvas>
<h1>
  Use ctrl-c and ctrl-v to copy and paste
</h1>

<ol>
  <li>Copy the textbox</li>
  <li>Run Notepad and type in some text "replacement text", then copy the text to the windows clipboard</li>
  <li>Select either the original textbox or the copy it doesn't matter which and paste in the text copied from notepad</li>
  <li>The result is that it pastes a new textbox instead of the selected text in the textbox</li>
</ol>
<h3>
If you re-run this example and just use the existing textbox it will successfully paste the text from notepad.
</h3>
```

Comment: Because its not saving in browser clipboard, your data get assigned to variable `_clipboard`.

Comment: Check here:https://jsfiddle.net/mariusturcu93/qzkpon02/57/ and you will see what happends. As @Durga said you use `_clipboard` variable.In `Paste` function you call `setActiveObject` and `requestRenderAll` and the current edit object will be focus out. My solution is to check if your activeObject has `isEditing` on true. If yes you need to prevent your custom paste function

Comment: Thanks @Durga and Marius that worked good here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Larry_Robertson/xbo1n0zy/

Answer (score 0):

Pasting the solution given in the comments by Larry Robertson, just in case jsfiddle removes it.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
   selection: true,
 });

 textBox = new fabric.Textbox("copy me", {
   fontSize: 24,
   fontFamily: 'Verdana',
   fill: '#000000',
   textAlign: 'left',
   width: 200, // for 20 characters
   top: 0,
   left: 0
 });
 textBox.setControlsVisibility({
   mt: false, // middle top disable
   mb: false, // midle bottom
   ml: true, // middle left
   mr: true, // middle right
   tl: false, // top left
   tr: false, // top right
   bl: false, // bottom left
   br: false // bottom right
 });
 canvas.add(textBox);
 canvas.renderAll();




 var _clipboard = null;

 function Copy() {
   // clone what are you copying since you
   // may want copy and paste on different moment.
   // and you do not want the changes happened
   // later to reflect on the copy.
   if (canvas.getActiveObject()) {
     if (canvas.getActiveObject().isEditing == true) {
       return false;
     }
     canvas.getActiveObject().clone(function(cloned) {
       _clipboard = cloned;
     });
   }
 }

 function Paste() {
   // clone again, so you can do multiple copies.
   if (_clipboard == null) {
     return false;
   }
   if (canvas.getActiveObject().isEditing == true) {
     return false;
   }
   _clipboard.clone(function(clonedObj) {
     clonedObj.set({
       left: clonedObj.left + 20,
       top: clonedObj.top + 20,
       evented: true,
     });
     if (clonedObj.type === 'activeSelection') {
       // active selection needs a reference to the canvas.
       clonedObj.canvas = canvas;
       clonedObj.forEachObject(function(obj) {
         canvas.add(obj);
       });
       // this should solve the unselectability
       clonedObj.setCoords();
     } else {
       canvas.add(clonedObj);
     }
     _clipboard.top += 20;
     _clipboard.left += 20;
     //canvas.setActiveObject(clonedObj);
     // canvas.requestRenderAll();
     _clipboard == null
   });
 }


 $(document).keydown(function(e) {   
   if (e.which === 89 && e.ctrlKey) {
     // control + y
     //replay(redo, undo, '#undo', this);
   } else if (e.which === 90 && e.ctrlKey) {
     // control + z
     //replay(undo, redo, '#redo', this);
   } else if (e.which === 67 && e.ctrlKey) {
     // control + c
     Copy();
   } else if (e.which === 86 && e.ctrlKey) {
     // control + v
     Paste();
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stealth-apsvaw.streamhoster.com/fabric.js-2.4.1/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" class="context-menu-one" width="864" height="450" style="border:2px solid black"></canvas>
<h1>
  Use ctrl-c and ctrl-v to copy and paste
</h1>

<ol>
  <li>Copy the textbox</li>
  <li>Run Notepad and type in some text "replacement text", then copy the text to the windows clipboard</li>
  <li>Select either the original textbox or the copy it doesn't matter which and paste in the text copied from notepad</li>
  <li>The result is that it pastes a new textbox instead of the selected text in the textbox</li>
</ol>
<h3>
  If you re-run this example and just use the existing textbox it will successfully paste the text from notepad.
</h3>
```